# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to store value by using code below but it is giving me error.

```
int dqty=  Convert.ToInt32(from row in result.AsEnumerable()
where row.Field<string>("batch_num") == k_batch.ToString() 
select row.Field<int>("qty"));
```

Basically i want to retrieve value of "qty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disregarding your other problems, you cant convert a list/collection to an integer

You'll need to use `FirstOrDefault` or similar

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence contains no elements.

**Example**

```
 int dqty = (from row in result.AsEnumerable()
              where row.Field<string>("batch_num") == k_batch.ToString() 
              select row.Field<int>("qty")).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update**

Further exmaple

```
var list = new List<int>()  {23, 345, 546, 345};

var result = (
    from row in list
    where row > 23
    select row).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
345
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z8cXxQ)

Comment: int doesnot contain for .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: what if i dont want to retrieve Default value ? Because Default value can change my results.

Comment: Your above code returns me 546 if value is not found in DataTable. I don't want this. Because it will change the results.